# How to spawn a certain block everywhere in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was on youtube and saw a player use a command where it placed lava on the whole map. I want to know how to do this. Can anyone help?

I play on Mcpe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step#1: Find Your Location by Setting the World Spawn Point**

A quick way to find your current location is to set the game spawn point to your current position. Doing so is very straightforward:

**Step#1:** Start a Minecraft PE 0.16.0 (or higher) game with cheats enabled.
Click the speak or talk icon.
To set your position to the new spawn point, type: **/setworldspawn**

Minecraft PE will show the syntax as: **/setworldspawn [spawnPoint: x y z]**

The parameters in brackets are optional and we don’t know them anyway. For our purposes, simply **omit the brackets and their contents entirely.**
Hit enter to send the command.
The command will respond by reporting back: **You have been teleported to < current x >, < current y >, < current z >**

**Step#2:** Place two blocks at opposing corners. For example: One at top right, another one down left. Use commands as in step 1 to find out their coordinates. Then , type: **/fill < right block's x coordinate > < right block's y coordinate > < right block's z coordinate > < left block's x coordinate >  < left block's z coordinate > minecraft:blockname 0 replace** then hit send.

In case you didn't understand: **[-->Click me<--](http://youtube.com/watch?v=QuFV9ZmAECk)**